# Proxy problems with Drupal 7.20

Tags: proxies

I have an installation of Drupal 7.20. I've entered the proxy settings in the default.settings.php but it's still unable to check on updates. A simple test with a dummy page which executes

```
http://updates.drupal.org/release-history/drupal/7.x?version=7.20')); ?>
```

Results in the following error message

> object(stdClass)#62 (2) { ["code"]=> int(-110) ["error"]=> string(20) "Connection timed out" }

Which leads me to believe the proxy settings are not being detected

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, changing default.settings.php won't do anything. This file is only there to be copied into settings.php when the site is first installed - so if you change it after settings.php has been created it will do nothing at all.

You might try [this module for proxy settings](https://www.drupal.org/project/http_proxy) (though don't believe it when it claims to have a working version for D8)